# Need help making custom protocol for SKScene

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, protocols

I have no experience with making my own protocols and I am trying to make one so that I can send `GameController` dpad values to an `SKScene`. Everything is connected and builds properly, but my `SKScene` is not receiving any information.

Here is my Main View Controller:

```
import GameController
import ...

protocol GetsDpadFromController {
    func dpadValueUpdate(dpadValue: CGPoint)
}

class GameViewController: UIViewController {

    var joystickController: GCController!
    var dpadData: GetsDpadFromController? = nil

    override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

        NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "addController:", name: GCControllerDidConnectNotification, object: nil)

    }
}

  func addController(sender: NSNotificationCenter) {
    self.joystickController = GCController.controllers().first
    self.joystickController.microGamepad?.reportsAbsoluteDpadValues = true
    self.joystickController.microGamepad?.valueChangedHandler = { (gamepad, element) -> Void in
        if element == self.joystickController.microGamepad?.dpad {
            let x: CGFloat = CGFloat((self.joystickController.microGamepad?.dpad.xAxis.value)!)
            let y: CGFloat = CGFloat((self.joystickController.microGamepad?.dpad.yAxis.value)!)
            let touchPosition: CGPoint = CGPointMake(x, y)

             if let delegate = self.dpadData {
                delegate.dpadValueUpdate(touchPosition)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And here is my SKScene:

```
class Page04: SKScene, GetsDpadFromController {

    override init(size: CGSize){
    super.init(size: size)

    }

    func dpadValueUpdate(dpadValue: CGPoint) {
        print(dpadValue)
    }

}
```

Nothing prints from `dpadValueUpdate` in the SKScene so I do not get the controller data. I have never made my own protocol before so I'm not too sure what I am doing wrong.

Does anyone know why my `SKScene` is not receiving data?

Comment: Where do you set the `dpadData` on your `GameViewController`?

Comment: I haven't technically set it...there are two tutorials I found online and neither of them set it. I am confused about that part because it doesn't make sense why you would not set it. I have tried to set it but cannot figure out how. I think it's just staying nil.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You properly declared the `GetsDpadFromController` protocol and made your `Page04` scene conform to it.

### The missing part

Looking at your code, the `dpadData` property in `GameViewController` will always be `nil`.

So the body of this IF will never be executed.

```
if let delegate = self.dpadData {
    delegate.dpadValueUpdate(touchPosition)
}
```

Replace the IF with this

```
let skView = self.view as! SKView
if let delegate = skView.scene as? GetsDpadFromController {
    delegate.dpadValueUpdate(touchPosition)
}
```

Now you are checking if the current scene does conform to `GetsDpadFromController` (which will be true for `Page04`) and if so you are invoking the `dpadValueUpdate` in your scene.

Let me know if it does work.

Comment: This is working great and I get the touchPosition in my SKScene. Thank you `appzYourLife` for  the thorough explanation.